# How can I get the port of session.getRequestURI() in a Java EE @ServerEndpoint

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, java-websocket

In my Java EE - Eclipse Oxygen environment with tomcat9 the port is always -1(should be 62114)!

```
@OnOpen
@Encoded
public void onOpen(@PathParam("BenutzerID") Long BenutzerID, @PathParam("Grad") long Kontaktgrad,
        @PathParam("Accesskey") String Accesskey, Session session, EndpointConfig config) {

    this.port = session.getRequestURI().getPort();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the port is not defined, the [`getPort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getPort()) method will return `-1`. That's the case when the *default port* is used.

- `80` is the default port for `http` and `ws` URI schemes.
- `443` is the default port for `https` and `wss` URI schemes.

---

From the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), the document that defines the WebSocket protocol:

> By default, the WebSocket Protocol uses port `80` for regular WebSocket
> connections and port `443` for WebSocket connections tunneled over
> Transport Layer Security (TLS).

Comment: I use port 62114  and 62115!

Comment: Why do you need to get the port, by the way?

Comment: I must know which of the two ports is used. ,

Comment: Or can I bind the socket to a special port?